# how to configure a rect after drawing with pygame?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, pygame, config

Like Tkinter you can configure your widget after drawing it using `ex: widget.config(...)`,
How can I change the color of a rectangle (for example) after drawing it in pygame?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood what [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/about) is.

Comment: there are no widgets in `pygame`, it has more "primitive" stuff (from which you could create widgets if you wanted, in which case you could add something like `config` but you would have to do it yourself)

Comment: Actually, I know what pygame is, but I'm asking if I can reconfigure for examlpe a rect after drawing it (such as its color or dimension).
if you understand me and you have the answer so plz help me. Thank you

Comment: @Houssem_coder *"Actually, I know what pygame is, but I'm asking if I can reconfigure for examlpe a rect after drawing it ..."* - This question clearly shows that you don't know what pygame is. A rectangle drawn with pygame is just a bunch of pixels of the same color on the screen. There is nothing that you can configure.

Comment: @Rabbid76 wouldn't drawing over those pixels but with a different color count as configuring?

Comment: @Matiiss Not in the meaning of `widget.config(...)`

Comment: @Rabbid76 I somehow think that `tkinter` does the same under the hood: redraws the widget but just for example in case of changing text, places pixels in some other place (after redrawing the widget's base (which changes all the pixels in the area of the widget to the base color, then draws text (changes some pixels again)))

Comment: @Matiiss The point is that tkinter is a completely different level of abstraction. A possible implementation of tkinter could use pygame to do the drawing.

Comment: @Rabbid76 and Matiiss, Thank you guys, that was really helpful... I think I've to deepen my understanding of these modules.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of a surface, you simply change the variable then draw it to the screen. For example:

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit as sys_exit

pygame.init()
WINDOW_SIZE = (800, 600)
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

player_surf = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
player_rect = player_surf.get_rect(center=(200, 200))

draw_red = True


def quit_game():
    pygame.quit()
    sys_exit()


def draw():
    WINDOW.fill("White")

    if draw_red:
        player_surf.fill("Red")  # Now the player color is red.
    else:
        player_surf.fill("Blue")  # Now the player color is blue.

    WINDOW.blit(player_surf, player_rect)
    pygame.display.update()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit_game()
    left, middle, right = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if left:
        draw_red = False  # When you press left mouse button, player's color should change

    draw()
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
```